# YouTube API Tag clean up

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

## Recommend removal

The following tags serve no purpose other than to cause confusion. We have [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) and [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) tags. These are the tags that should be used because there is only one YouTube API and there is no need to have the v3. Language specific questions for these APIs should fall under the client library for that language, i.e. [google-api-dotnet-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-dotnet-client) and [google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client). There is no reason to have a YouTube tag for each of these languages.

- [youtube.net-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube.net-api)
- [youtube-v3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-v3-api)
- [youtube-data-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api-v3)
- [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3)
- [python-youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-youtube-api)

## Recommend renaming

YouTube Player API is an API used for playing YouTube videos. There are actually two of them one for JavaScript and another for Android.

I am thinking we should have a general YouTube-Player-API tag but if someone thinks that it's a good idea to split them, then a YouTube-Player-JS tag with a synonym to [youtube-iframe-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api) would probably be the best option, IMO. However, [android-youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-youtube-api) needs a rename to YouTube-Player-Android.

- [youtube-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-javascript-api) https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- [android-youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-youtube-api)  https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/
- [youtube-iframe-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api) https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- [youtubeplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtubeplayer)

Comment: Can't we just have 1 tag `youtube-api` to encompass all of this? Or maybe two: `youtube-data-api` and `youtube-player-api`. Fewer variations makes it easier for people to tag correctly. In my experience, API tags are usually poor quality at the best of times, filled with people who didn't bother to read the documentation. It's also future-proof in case they introduce more, or change the specific name, etc.

Comment: @Michael  That wouldn't really work the YouTube-Data-api is the Rest api for accessing YouTube data https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/  its completely different from the YouTube Player API  which allows you to play videos.

Comment: @Michael there is no other link for a YouTube-Javascript-api i assumed is a tag for the Player but it could also have been missused for the Google-apis-js-client im not exactly sure what it was used for.  Check the tag wiki you can see what the oringal author thought it was meant to be used for.

Comment: Sidenote: Shouldn't  [tag:youtube-analytics-api] be  divided into [tag:youtube-reporting-api] and [tag:youtube-analytics-api]? Aren't they two separate apis? Doc: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting#key-differences

Comment: @TheMaster yes they are two separate APIs but they are very closely linked.  Splitting them does make a sense.

Comment: Sidenote:  I have been thinking it might be best to do away with YouTube-api and just stick with YouTube-Data-api i cant come up with a reason to have both of those.

Comment: Given different end points, I think [tag:youtube-analytics-api] should be split up. Regardless, I agree with *best to do away with YouTube-api and just stick with YouTube-Data-api*

Comment: There were only 10 questions with [python-youtube-api], and only 3 of those were without [youtube-api] so I went ahead and merged them. The other two synonyms you've proposed for the language specific APIs are now approved as well (did not merge yet). Not sure what to make of [youtubeplayer] and I can't exactly clean the tags either

Comment: rename YouTubePlayer to YouTube-Player-API  catch all tag for Iframe and android.  or rename android-YouTube-API to YouTube-Player-Android-api   then we make Youtube-Iframe-api catch all to iframe and js so youtube-javsacript-api should synonym to that.

Comment: I removed all the YouTube-api and YouTube-data-api tags from all questions tagged with YoutubePlayer